# Python Pattern Matching and parsing

Tags: python, loops, pattern-matching

I want to dump the following information whenever there is a match in the **EVENT NAME**

```
1. Event ID
2. Interview ID
```

Is there any way to traverse back and forth once there is a valid match in the Event Name.

Sample File Content which has around 1000 events with similar structure:

```
Event ID: 17013
Event Component: FIS
Event Type: VISA/NOA/CHAP
HINT: NORTH
Event Creator: soc-cvt
**Event Name: Up_MemRd_Unaligned_mburst_ge_0x8**
InterView ID: 22282
InterView Folder ID: 624
InterView Folder Name: SC_MainFabric_Transactions
Event Priority: 3
Sample Mode: per-seed
Event Conditional: !conditionals
CHAP Counter 0: counter_0,sum,>,10,warn`enter code here`

Event ID: 2324
Event Component: state
Event Type: VISA/NOA/CHAP
.........
```

Comment: 1. Read an entire event entry. 2. check the event name. 3. if it matches you have all the information you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
eid, iid = -1,-1
search_for='Up_MemRd_Unaligned_mburst_ge_0x8'
with open("input") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if 'Event ID' in line: eid = line.split(':')[1].strip()
        elif 'InterView ID' in line and name:
            iid = line.split(':')[1].strip()
            print "1.", eid
            print "2.", iid
        elif 'Event Name' in line:
            name = line.split(':')[1].strip(" *")
            if name != search_for: name = ""
```